c# .net сохранение/загрузка состояния пользовательских сессий
День добрый.
Имеется веб-сервер kestrel и запущенное на нем приложение .net
Размышляю, как относительно просто и быстро сделать функционал сохранения состояния пользовательских сессий перед обновлением сервера, после чего сессии нужно восстановить.
Сама публикация уже автоматизирована, событие выключения сервера уже отлавливается, в этом месте перед выключением можно закинуть в БД данные сессии и при старте приложения восстановить состояния сессий из БД.
Хочется сделать обновление веб-приложение более "невидимым" для пользователей.
Между клиентами и kestrel есть еще nginx, на который можно повесить заглушку, которая будет "держать" запрос, пока обновляется сервер(20-30 сек). Для пользователя это должно выглядеть как долгий ответ, но после перезапуска сервер не просит его авторизоваться снова. Значение его сессионной куки уже должно быть на сервере(прочитано из БД при старте сервера)
Имеет-ли это какой-то практический смысл или лучше пойти по другому пути для обеспечения нужного функционала?

Да обычно никто до такой степени не заморачиваются, просто делают обновление в тот момент, когда сервер наименее загружен, да и всё. Если вы, конечно, не обновляетесь по 10 раз на дню, тогда это может кому-то доставить неудобства. А так ну раз в месяц сессия отвалится ненадолго у небольшого кол-ва пользователей - это не страшно.

Обычно для обеспечения непрерывности обслуживания обновленный сервер запускают, пока старый еще работает и перенаправляют на него новые запросы, а старый выключают только после того, как тот закончил работать со всеми оставшимися запросами.

@user7860670 Да, вот это хороший вариант бесшовного перехода. Но нужен как минимум второй сервер и балансировщик, через которой это можно сделать.

@CrazyElf Нужен не просто второй сервер, а вторая БД старой версии. Так как сервер обновляется вместе с БД, если вместе с сервером не обновить структуру БД - сервер работать не будет. Но если новый сервер работает с другой версией БД, и БД работают параллельно - нужно после синхронизации перенести данные из старой БД в новую. На этом задача сильно усложняется.

@kocapb Ну вам таки принципиально "бесшовное" обновление? Я бы просто анонсировал "окно" в обслуживании, где-то ночью в рабочие дни, когда пользователей мало. Обычно так все делают. Мало кто парится на эту тему прям.

Начните с выяснения того, что именно входит в пользовательскую сессию и что вы вообще пытаетесь сохранить. Возможно, всё уже реализовано в фреймворке...

Если вы говорите о аутентификации пользователя - то сохранение этих данных работает из коробки с настройками по умолчанию, вам надо лишь не разломать этот механизм.

Если вопрос в бесшовном рестарте, то как выше советуют, вам нужен load balancer (nginx вроде умеет)   и запасной сервер куда слать запросы, если храните сессию в БД, то второй сервер её тоже может считать. Обновления БД делайте обратно совместимыми хотя бы между 2 деплоями, иначе простоев вам не избежать.
